# Sane не видит сканер

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть принтер [Canon PIXMA MG2440](http://www.canon.ru/printers/inkjet/pixma/pixma_mg2440/), и ПК с Ubuntu Desktop 14(x32).
На нём стоит [`sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane).
`sane-find-scanner` находит его:

```
$ sane-find-scanner -q
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x176c [MG2400 series]) at libusb:001:002
```

версия `scanimage`:

```
$ scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.25; backend version 1.0.23
```

`scanimage` не находит его:

```
$ scanimage -L
No scanners were identified...
```

lsusb выводит:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04a9:176c Canon, Inc.
```

Попробовал в `/etc/sane.d/canon.conf` добавить:  `usb 0x04a9 0x176c`.
Ничего не поменялось.
При запуски *Xsane* пишет что нету сканеров.

`$ ls /dev/usb`  выводит:
`lp0`

`dmesg` после подключения выводит:

> [ 7902.876229] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
> [ 7903.012512] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=176c
> [ 7903.012531] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
> [ 7903.012544] usb 1-1: Product: MG2400 series
> [ 7903.012556] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Canon
> [ 7903.012567] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: E20563
> [ 7903.022279] usblp 1-1:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x176C
> [ 7904.235349] usblp0: removed
> [ 7904.250411] usblp 1-1:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x176C

`SANE_DEBUG_PIXMA=128 scanimage -L` выводит:

> [pixma] pixma is compiled with pthread support.
> [pixma] pixma version 0.17.0
> [pixma] sanei_bjnp_find_devices:
> [pixma] Added all configured scanners, now do auto detection...
>
> > (X5)
> > [pixma] lo is not a valid IPv4 interface, skipping...
> > [pixma] eth0 is not a valid IPv4 interface, skipping...
> > [pixma] wlan0 is not a valid IPv4 interface, skipping...
> > [pixma] lo is not a valid IPv4 interface, skipping...
> > [pixma] eth0 is not a valid IPv4 interface, skipping...
> > [pixma] wlan0 is not a valid IPv4 interface, skipping...
> > [pixma] lo is not a valid IPv4 interface, skipping...
> > [pixma] eth0 is IPv4 capable, sending broadcast..
>
> [pixma] scanner discovery finished...
> [pixma] pixma_find_scanners() found 0 devices
>
> No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something
> different, check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and
> detected by the sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read
> the documentation which came with this software (README, FAQ,
> manpages).

Что я не так делаю?
Возможно, нужно что-то ещё установить?

Comment: 1. отключите сканер. 2. очистите буфер сообщений: `sudo dmesg -c`. 3. подключите сканер. 4. подождите пару секунд. 5. выполните команду `sudo dmesg` и её вывод (полностью) добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @alexander barakin, добавил в вопрос.

Comment: http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/sane-devel/2014-September/032658.html

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , обновил sane-backends до 1.0.25, теперь `sane-find-scanner` видит его, а всё остальное не поменялось. (обновил вопрос)

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу, вывод команды `$ SANE_DEBUG_SNAPSCAN=128 scanimage -L`

Comment: `SANE_DEBUG_SNAPSCAN=128 scanimage -L`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, добавил в вопрос

Comment: пардон, я что-то не подумал, что использоваться будет не *snapscan*, а *pixma* (судя по выводу [запроса](http://www.sane-project.org/cgi-bin/driver.pl?manu=&model=&bus=any&v=04a9&p=176c)). замените, пожалуйста вывод той команды на вывод `$ SANE_DEBUG_PIXMA=128 scanimage -L`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, исправил

Comment: нда. ничего полезного. на всякий случай, навскидку, уточню: 1. пользователь, от имени которого выполняется программа `scanimage`, входит в группу *scanner* (см. вывод программы `id`)? 2. пакет *libsane-extras* установлен?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, 1)Да (пробовал и от root  ,и от основного (они оба в этой группе)). 2)Установлен